# iPython 3 Notebook raising ImportError: No module named 'IPython.frontend.html'

Tags: python-3.x, import, ipython, importerror

The iPython 2 console and notebook as well as the iPython 3 console work fine on my system.

But running `ipython3 notebook` gives an `ImportError` saying `No module named 'IPython.frontend.html'` and [this traceback](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5857820).

I think it may have something to do with Ubuntu RR package problems, but I'm not sure.

10x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu split the notebook functionality away form the main `ipython3` package into `ipython3-notebook` in Raring.

Now installing `ipython3` should install `ipython3-notebook` for you automatically as it recommends it; but when I had this problem, Raring critically depended on a package of `python3` too high for `python3-zmq` which was depended on by `ipython3-notebook` causing `ipython3-notebook`' to not be installed (which I did not notice). *Whew...*

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to the fact that the package layout has been change and `IPython.frontend.html` is now `IPython.html`  do you have dev version installed by any chance ?

Comment: Uhh.,. no. The package name is `ipython3` and not something like `ipython3-dev` or w/e.

Comment: would Raring have splitted IPython in subpackages ? maybe there is a specific `IPython3-notebook` package...

Comment: <facepalm> There is and I remember trying to install it. But I hadn't noticed that it had failed b'coz python-zmq couldn't be installed. Now I have to go downgrading everything again b'coz RR is just incompatible with mostly everything... :(

Comment: Apparently a critical half of my system depends on a version of `python3` that is too high for `python3-zmq` which is depended upon by `ipython3-notebook`

Comment: hum... have a look a julian taylor PPA : https://launchpad.net/~jtaylor/+archive/ipython-dev it might help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and fixed it by upgrading ipython (using --upgrade)